# PHP function shows result but does not return it

Tags: php, function, return

I'm writing a code in PHP to find the next business day withing off days. This is my code:

```
function find_next_day($today,$days_array) {
    $day = new DateTime($today);
    $tomorrow = $day->modify('+1 day');
    $result = $tomorrow->format('Y-m-d');
    if (!in_array($result,$days_array)) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        find_next_day($result,$days_array);
    }
}

$off_days = array('2016-08-10','2016-08-25','2016-08-09','2016-08-11');
echo find_next_day('2016-08-09',$off_days); // I must get returned value as 2016-08-12
```

It's really strange that function does not return anything. But if I put `echo $result` before returning value in function, I can see the final result correctly!
What is my mistake here ?

Comment: `return find_next_day...`

Comment: Your return should not be buried in an IF statement.  If you want the function to return something, it has to return it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning the result in the function in the `else` statement.

```
function find_next_day($today,$days_array) {
    $day = new DateTime($today);
    $tomorrow = $day->modify('+1 day');
    $result = $tomorrow->format('Y-m-d');
    if (!in_array($result,$days_array)) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return find_next_day($result,$days_array);
    }
}
```

Try this one out. Should work.

Comment: Thank you @CoderDude for your fast assistance.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi you should also make sure there's a default return value and not encapsulating them in `if else`s.

If your problem was solved, you can accept the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to `return find_next_day();`

```
....
} else {
    return find_next_day($result,$days_array);
}
....
```

Comment: Thank you @mmm for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The answers saying you should `return find_next_day(...)` are correct.  However, you don't need a recursive function here.  Recursive algorithms are for traversing branching/nested hierarchies where you don't know how deep the branching/nesting goes.  In this case, you just want to evaluate a linear series of dates.

I recommend you use a simple `while` loop to check each date to see if it is a day off (maybe with a limit of 365 increments to `$day`).